# XML Password Obfuscation

Tags: java, xml, obfuscation

Is there a way to obfuscate part of an XML attribute?

I want to encrypt the user= and password= part of the following xml attribute so no one looking at the file can see the password.  Is there any way to do that using Java DOM?

```
<connectionString="Data Source=Winserver\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=haven;Integrated Security=false;user=admin;password="/>
```

If you can answer with Java code, that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't XML, so I removed the tag.

Comment: why is it not xml? I want to obfuscate an xml element

Comment: Take a look at this question. It's similar to yours and might point you in the right direction. "How can I protect MySQL username and password from decompiling?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442862 --

Comment: You could use XML encryption which is a spec to sign/encrypt XML or part of XML documents. But that would be overkill in this case.

Comment: what you're showing in your post is a plain old String containing `;` delimited data.  I'm sorry if my edits incorrectly re-interpret your question -- if they have, please rollback the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to encrypt XML Data.

Have a look at http://www.w3.org/Encryption/2001/ for more information.

I guess there are many ways to do that in Java, denpending on your XML Api you already have build in support for that. You may also wanna have a look at java digital signature api http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/dig_signature_api/

Answer (score 1):

I am not a java guy though. But I can help you with some procedures.

1. Find some encryption algorithm and base64 encoder
2. Encrypt your password with a static seed that your program knows only and base64 encode it.
3. Put the base64 encoded string next to `password=`

For decoding

1. Parse the base64 encoded portion of the password.
2. Decode the password with base64.
3. And decrypt the password with your seed.
4. Replace the base64 encoded string with your decoded/decrypted password.

You can try encryption algorithms like AES, TwoFish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the common way of keeping the connection string of an ASP.NET application private, is to put the connection string in the registry of the web server and then just load that value in the ASP website.

But even if you were opposed to the registry or wanted a cross-platform method, I think your best bet is to put the string someplace where outsiders can't read it. This may be outside the root web site directory (if this is a website), or prompt the user for it (don't store it at all), or hide it someplace else. On a Linux box, you could even chmod 700, to limit access only to the user that runs the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Silencio](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/silencio) library which you can use to remove or hash nodes from XML file. You can decide which nodes should be transformed (you may want to obfuscate only some such as password) and what change should be applied (clear the content, hash or custom)