# Encrypt a connection string, how?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I want to encrypt/hide my connection string in my database.java class. I allready searched the internet but I didn't find anything usefull, maybe I searched the wrong keywords? Here is my current code.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://database/db", "username", "password");
```

How can I hide the username and password? So only my application can see it? And you can't see it when you extract the jar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encrypt the connection string is not what you need! I suppose you need a better way to store your password. For this you should store passwords, in a separate file that the application reads when it starts. That is the only real way to prevent the password from leaking as a result of decompilation.

See this answer : [From a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195099/java-how-to-store-password-used-in-application/8195195#8195195)

Answer (score 0):

you can byte endcode the string in a method and make the method return a string. if you wish you could add your encryption alogrithm that extracts the actual string using the input bytess.

Comment: as Sanjay points out below, that is a better approach. Use a encryption api to extract the username, pwd, url from a properties file that goes with your app. This way you can also implement some licensing features.. (which is a bit more complicated)

Comment: One thing I'd like to add to this answer: avoid storing the encryption key with the encrypted data.