# How to protect the .jar file from being decompile java

Tags: java

How can I prevent the person that downloaded my java.jar which has my website mysql password and username on the connect class form being decompiled by a certain program. Is there a certain special class in java that let me do to secure my connect class?

Comment: The solution is to never put your password in such a position where this could be possible. In the medical field, this is what we call a "never event", similar to leaving surgical instruments in a patient. It shouldn't even be considered, and safeguards should be in prevent it from ever occurring.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot effectively prevent a MySQL password from being read out of your application — even if you take steps to encrypt the text of the password (which most obfuscation tools will not do), it will still be possible for a user to intercept the password as it is passed to the MySQL library.

Do not connect directly to MySQL from your client software. Build a web-accessible API to your database which only exposes the data it needs to and interact with that.

Comment: A much better answer than wangy's.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [obfuscation](http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators).

Comment: so it will protect my class from being decompiled?

Comment: No, it will only make it slightly harder.

Comment: When people decompile your class, lets say `com.example.class`, they will see `a.b.c`, which in a large scale project is essentially impossible to figure out. But all your value such as `String` will still be in plaintext. You should NEVER hard code your password, see this post for detail on dealing with this type of situation:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442862/how-can-i-protect-mysql-username-and-password-from-decompiling