# Publish app with open source and hide classes

Tags: java, security, jar

I wish to publish my app with open source as example for users. The problem is that I have class that downloads from ftp, and there is password and username written in the class. I wish to hide this information from user. I made an external jar file but with site like: http://jd.benow.ca/ that is Java Decompiler it can be easily opened, how can I hide and make it hard to hack to the username and password that written in one of my classes?

Comment: `"and there is password and username written in the class"` -- solution, don't do this. In fact, **never** do this.

Comment: So where to put them?

Comment: In a configuration file

Comment: But it still will be visible if I send some one my source code

Comment: [7 Tips to deal with sensitive information or password in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/best-practices-while-dealing-with.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of an open source project, use `web service` for assigning `username` and `password` to the user who is using project with there application. To implement this, you need to implement some SOAP base approach with `axis-2` in java, if that **LIB** is build in java and simply call the methods with your business logic.

Last but not the least, try to create username and password for the user who download's this **LIB** so that you don't need to share your username and password with the jar of source files .

Answer (score 1):

Creates a file where you'll register your username and password. Then you just have to never commit this file in your repository and not share it.

This topic is very similar to yours, maybe the answer will interest you: [How can I protect MySQL username and password from decompiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442862/how-can-i-protect-mysql-username-and-password-from-decompiling)